# Android realm sorting list of objects

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-java

How I can sort list of **RealmObjects** by two parametrs? For example first param is **name** (Need to sort it alphabetically), second parameter is a bit complicated and related to 3 dates: I have a range dates (for example **fromDate** **currentDate** and **toDate**). Need to put to the head of the list all items wich happening today. Also do not forget about alphabetically sorting.

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#findAllSorted-java.lang.String:A-io.realm.Sort:A-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically trying to sort a `realmList` depending on multiple parameters.
Here's the way to go:

```
String[] fields = {"name","fromDate","currentDate","toDate"};
Sort[] howToSort = {Sort.ASCENDING, Sort.ASCENDING, Sort.ASCENDING, Sort.ASCENDING};
```

And then, you simply do a usual realm selection:

```
realm.where(YourRealmObject.class).findAllSorted(fileds, howToSort);
```

As @EpicPandaForce commented, please check the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#findAllSorted-java.lang.String:A-io.realm.Sort:A-).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way..

```
RealmResults<Notification_History>notification_histories=realm.where(Notification_History.class).findAll().sort("notification_count");
```